# mingw "too many sections" bug while compiling huge header file in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

I was trying to compile exprtk.hpp file (https://exprtk.codeplex.com/) with mingw32(491_32) on Qt (win7). 
During compilation, I give this error message:

```
debug\main.o:-1: error: too many sections (35325)
```

I've been noticed that the exprtk.hpp file is huge (>32000 lines).
I've been trying optimization flags on compiler but It didn't help eighter.
I'll be appreciated if somebody help me...
Regards,

Comment: I think that the "bigobj" flag will solve my problem but my compiler cant recognize this flag.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Such huge header-only code is already bad design, i'd rather recommend to use another library, like [muParser](http://muparser.beltoforion.de/).

Your problem was already discussed in other threads, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596876/object-file-has-too-many-sections).

> As you've already noticed, passing /bigobj to Microsoft's compiler
> causes it to output a munged COFF format with up to 2^31 sections,
> which "should be enough for anybody."
>
> I've tested this new option with MinGW-w64 and it works. You need to
> pass -Wa,-mbig-obj to gcc to opt-in to big objects (-Wa means pass
> this option to the assembler). –  Francis Gagné

Comment: Thanks, First of all I've tested -Wa, -mbig-obj option and It didn't worked. Second, I'm looking for a library which support "logic operations", "control and loop structures".

Comment: @Mosi That's already more than a math parser should provide, you should rather add a light scripting language, like [Lua](http://www.lua.org/).

Comment: The option `-Wa,-mbig-obj` didn't work for me (invalid option), but the last post (Shaheryar.Akram) solved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

You can by adding the compilation flags `-flto -Wl,-allow-multiple-definition` and you can add `-fuse-linker-plugin`

`-Wa,-mbig-obj` do not work on `x86/32bits` architecture (only `x64`)

Comment: Worked for me. Only need the `-fto` option. I also have to separate all my class methods into separate compilation units (.cpp). Thanks a lot.