# Why is GDB "jumping back" when debugging with c source codes

Tags: android, debugging, gdb, kernel

I'm debugging the goldfish android kernel (version 3.4), with kernel sources.

Now I found that gdb sometimes jump back and forth between lines, e.g consider c source code like the following:

```
char *XXX;
int a;
...

if (...)
{

}
```

When I reached the `if` clause, I type in `n` and it will jump back to the `int a` part. Why is that?

If I execute that command again, it would enter the brackets in the `if`.

If possible, I want to avoid that part, and enter the if directly (of course, if condition matches)

Comment: I've not debugged in that environment, but I would guess it's to do with optimisations / code-rearragnement that the compiler has done.  For example, if the `a` was only used inside the `if`, then it may not get created/initialised unless the `if` is entered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When I reached the if clause, I type in n and it will jump back to the int a part. Why is that?

Because your code is compiled with optimization on, and the compiler can (and often does) re-arrange instructions of your program in such a way that instructions "belonging" to different source lines are interleaved (code motion optimizations attempt (among other things) to move load instructions to long before their results are needed; this helps to hide memory latency).

If you are using `gcc-4.8` or later, build your sources with `-Og`. Else, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7509066/50617) answer.