# how to set debug and optimization flag with meson

Tags: linux, gcc, optimization, meson-build

I use meson 0.53.2 on ubuntu 20.04.
I would like to have a maximally optimized executable (`-Ofast`) but contain all debug symbols (`-g3`)

- If I use `--buildtype=release` it optimizes `-O2` and the executable contains no debug symbol.
- If I use `--buildtype=debug` it does not optimize at all and uses `-g`.
- If I use `--buildtype=debugoptimized` it optimizes `-O2` and uses `-g`.

I tried to use `--debug` which seems not to work, because the executable does not contain any debug symbol. Instead if I use `-Ddebug=true` the debug symbols are there but with the flag `-g`.

So how do I get `gcc` to compile with `-Ofast -g3` flags in the least dirty way possible?

Comment: Your best bet is to stick to `debugoptimized`, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493947/whats-the-best-g-optimization-level-when-building-a-debug-target) on the why

Comment: @nielsdg I do not want it to be debuggable at all. I need few things, one among all the stack trace. But it is absolutely necessary that the optimization is `-Ofast`. If I use `dubugoptimized` the optimization is only `-O2`.

Answer (score 1):

From the commandline, you can switch higher level of optimization with option `optimization=3`. It gives you `-O3` instead `-O2`.

By editing meson script, you can set any flags.

```
if get_option('buildtype') == 'custom'
  add_project_arguments('-Ofast', '-g3',  language : 'cpp')
endif
```

And in case you cannot modify meson script, you may alter environment variables

```
CXXFLAGS="-Ofast -g3" meson --buildtype=custom build_c
```

And `--reconfigure` seems to not see environment variables.