# How to build a certain library with debug mode while other library build with release mode

Tags: cmake

I have a whole project and usually the project is build with release mode, but sometimes, I know certain lib have problem , I want to debug it and want to build this library to debug mode and other libs remain release mode, how can I do that?

Suppose the `lib_foo` is that lib need to build with debug mode, I tried with `target_compile_option`:

```
target_compile_option(lib_foo PRIVATE -O0 -g)
```

After add above line in the lib's cmake file and make with `make VERBOSE=1` to build the `lib_foo` library, I found following compile options in the terminal,

```
-O3 -DNDEBUG   -O0 -g
```

the `-O3 -DNDEBUG` flags is from the global release build compile flags, and the `-O0 -g` is from `target_compile_option`, so my `lib_foo` is build with debug mode with `-O0 -g`? But run a unittest which depends on `lib_foo`, the performance of the unittest is not affect, I am not sure if above is right.

Is this the right way to build a certain lib with debug mode? or is there any better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string(REPLACE "-O3 -DNDEBUG" "-O0 -g" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})` or `string(REPLACE "-O3 -DNDEBUG" "-O0 -g" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE})` in your lib_foo/CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: this works, but the compile flags added will propagate to the folder included in lib_foo/CMakeLists.txt, if not want that happen, can add one line in the subfolder of foo's CMakeLists.txt, like 'string(REPLACE "-O0 -g" "-O3 -DNDEBUG" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE})' to recover and let the change only affects lib_foo

Answer (score 1):

> sometimes, I know certain lib have problem , I want to debug it and want to build this library to debug mode and other libs remain release mode, how can I do that? [...] or is there any better way to handle this?

The easiest way is to just use the `RelWithDebInfo` configuration instead of trying to mix configurations. This produces a moderately optimized build with debug symbols.

Comment: thanks for the answer. sometimes the -O3 option from Release or RelWithDebInfo optimised out too much info and it's not possible to use gdb to print variable values or run program step by step.

Comment: @BruceSun - you can override `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO` to be something like `-Og -g3` (on gcc) instead of the default, which is `-O2 -g` (not `-O3`)

Comment: typo here ? `-Og -g3` should be `-O2 -g3`?

Comment: @BruceSun - no typo. `-Og` is debugger friendly optimization. Take a look at the man page.

Comment: Glad to know that, according to here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16179105/4277805 , seems with '-Og', the whole program will slow down. In my case,  the run time for the whole program will be serveral hours when compiled with '-O' flag and when compiled with '-O2', it will be less than an hour, so that's why I need seprate compile flags for a certain lib, I expect this will not affect the whole run time much and also can debug easliy.